# Adding "linked accounts" (e.g., Twitter, Facebook) to a Rails 3 website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, devise

This isn't a question about how to use Twitter or Facebook API, but a simpler one about how to keep the databases in sync. What I want to do is to create a NEW linked account, and then attach that to the current user. I KNOW that my code currently is nonfunctional:

On the Edit Profile page

```
<%= f.label :account %> <i>(link another account to this profile)</i><br />

<% form_for @user.linked_accounts do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :username %>
  <%= f.collection_select :service, User::POSSIBLE_SERVICES, :to_s, :to_s, 
   :include_blank => true
  %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

How do I get it to submit into a devise database? It's definitely the " form_for @user.linked_accounts " I need to fix. I changed it to @user and I get a no-method error because :service is only defined in a linked account. I think that what I need to do is to create a new linked account, and then do the form_for @user.new_account.

The error I receive is:


`SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: linked_accounts.user_id: SELECT "linked_accounts".* FROM "linked_accounts" WHERE ("linked_accounts".user_id = 1)`

Comment: the error you receive signify you havn't this column in your database try to fix it first

Comment: i know -- the problem is that i need to create a new linked account for the current user and i don't know how

Comment: you want to link existing users to twitter, facebook etc... i'm right ? Why you didn't use omniauth ?

Comment: this isn't about the twitter facebook api. this is a MUCH easier question about how to getting the user database to link up with the account database.

Comment: ah sorry i'm not so good in english ... you just want to add a table or a column linked to user ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a railscast that deals with this. It uses an authorisations table which belongs_to the user table so you can add twitter, facebook etc... to the user

The cast is over 2 episodes and uses omniauth which is a really neat solution. You can find them here
http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1
http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2

Answer (score 0):

if i correctly understand your problem it's may be a solution for you to :

- create a new model to contain social network information
- use [nested model](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes) to allow adding social via the edit user form

And that's it